# Is possible to change a property inside a item and return the item itself?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a code like this on my app

```js
var name = 'TesT'; 
var nameLowercase = name && name.toLowerCase (), 
    namesToTest = ['asd', 'asd1', 'TesT'];

var findCorrectName = R.pipe(
    R.map(R.toLower),     
    R.any(R.equals(nameLowercase))
);

var hasFoundName = findCorrectName (namesToTest);

return hasFoundName;
```

But, now I need to do a search in a list of objects and the property 'name' must be put to lowercase. When found an object that matches my search, I need to get it.

I've read the documentation but I couldn't find a solution.

```js
var name = 'TesT'; 
var nameLowercase = name && name.toLowercase (), 
namesToTest = [ { name : 'asd', otherProperties... },
                { name : 'asd1', otherProperties... },
                { name : 'TesT', otherProperties... }];

var findByCorrectName = R.pipe(
    R.map(
        R.pipe(R.prop('name'), R.toLower)),
        R.find(R.propEq('name', nameLowercase))
    );

var foundObject = findByCorrectName (namesToTest);

return foundObject;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would find this a straightforward way to solve your problem:

```
const items = [{name : 'asd', x: 1}, {name : 'asd1', x: 2}, {name : 'TesT', x: 3}];

const byNameCi = curry((name, items) => find(
  where({name: pipe(toLower, equals(toLower(name)))}),
  items,
));

byNameCi('TEST', items); //=> {name: "TesT", x: 3}
```

The `curry` might not be necessary for your use case, but it would also allow this:

```
const findAsd = byNameCi('Asd');
// later
findAsd(items); //=> {name: "asd", x: 1}
```

Note that this returns your original values, without the toLowerCase transformation.  If you want to return ones with transformed names, then I might alter it like this:

```
const byTransformedNameCi = curry((name, items) => find(
  where({name: pipe(toLower, equals(toLower(name)))}),
  map(evolve({name: toLower}), items),
));

byTransformedNameCi('TEST', items); //=> {name: "test", x: 3}
```

Or, as you say, using [`lensProp`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp) and [`over`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#over) instead of [`evolve`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve).

While it's probably possible to make these point-free, these are already fairly readable, so I can't see a good reason to spend any effort on it.

You can see these approaches on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20items%20%3D%20%5B%7Bname%20%3A%20%27asd%27%2C%20x%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7Bname%20%3A%20%27asd1%27%2C%20x%3A%202%7D%2C%20%7Bname%20%3A%20%27TesT%27%2C%20x%3A%203%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20byNameCi%20%3D%20curry%28%28name%2C%20items%29%20%3D%3E%20find%28%0A%20%20where%28%7Bname%3A%20pipe%28toLower%2C%20equals%28toLower%28name%29%29%29%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20items%2C%0A%29%29%3B%0A%0AbyNameCi%28%27TEST%27%2C%20items%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7Bname%3A%20%22TesT%22%2C%20x%3A%203%7D%0A%0Aconst%20findAsd%20%3D%20byNameCi%28%27Asd%27%29%3B%0AfindAsd%28items%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7Bname%3A%20%22asd%22%2C%20x%3A%201%7D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20byTransformedNameCi%20%3D%20curry%28%28name%2C%20items%29%20%3D%3E%20find%28%0A%20%20where%28%7Bname%3A%20pipe%28toLower%2C%20equals%28toLower%28name%29%29%29%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28evolve%28%7Bname%3A%20toLower%7D%29%2C%20items%29%2C%0A%29%29%3B%0A%0AbyTransformedNameCi%28%27TEST%27%2C%20items%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7Bname%3A%20%22TesT%22%2C%20x%3A%203%7D%0A)**.

---

You asked in your title about transforming a property and returning the object.  Ramda will not actually alter your data; if you're looking for that, Ramda is not the right library for you.  But it will return a new object with that property transformed, and it has many functions that do this in various ways, including the ones we've already mentioned, [`assoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc), [`adjust`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#adjust), and others.

Comment: What amazing answer! Thank you! I think I'm understanding this library better now. Of course, I need to keep studying, but you answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [function over](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#over), it was just I need.

```js
var name = 'TesT',
    nameLowercase = name && name.toLowerCase(), 
    namesToTest = [ { name : 'asd' },
                    { name : 'asd1' },
                    { name : 'TesT' }];

var findByCorrectName = R.pipe(
                          R.map(R.over(R.lensProp('name'), R.toLower)),     
                          R.find(R.propEq('name', nameLowercase))
                        );

var hasFoundName = findByCorrectName (namesToTest);

return hasFoundName;
```

Comment: Can I assume you mean `R.find(R.propEq('name', nameLowercase))` ?  Without the `'name'` argument, this won't work.

Comment: @ScottSauyet You are right.. I missed the 'name' as argument.. Thanks, I fixed my answer now